# change templates for new members

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, automated-refactoring, roslynator

when I do refactoring in visual studio (2019) and I say "generate field", it per default always adds the "private" keyword before the new field. I don't want this. How can I modify this behavior?

I am not event sure if this functionality is provided by visual studio itself or by roslinator.

```
private int foo; // no!
int foo; // yes!
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go in the `Tools`|`Code Snippets Manager...` menu:

[image: Code Snippets Manager... menu]

It will open the code snippets manager.

- Select `CSharp` in the language drop down.
- In the tree go to `Refactoring`|`Generate field`

[image: code snippets manager]

It will give you the location of the snippet, on my machine (with French locale) it's:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\GenerateField.snippet
```

You can then edit the file to change the accessibility to the desired value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Generate Field</Title>
            <Description>Snippet for the field created by the 'Generate Field' refactoring</Description>
            <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Refactoring</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal Editable="true">
                    <ID>accessibility</ID>
                    <!-- put public here, actually on my machine it is already public -->
                    <Default>public</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal Editable="true">
                    <ID>modifiers</ID>
                    <Default></Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal Editable="true">
                    <ID>type</ID>
                    <Default>type</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal Editable="true">
                    <ID>signature</ID>
                    <Default>signature</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp">
                <![CDATA[$end$$accessibility$ $modifiers$ $type$ $signature$;]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

But you can also create your own snippet based on this one, call it 'Generate Public Field' and register it as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019).

**Edit:**

I did not find anything about this in [Roslynator sources](https://github.com/JosefPihrt/Roslynator). It definitly looks like a [VS quick action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-field-property-local?view=vs-2019).
There was a bug in Roslyn/VS about something similar [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/27716) and was related to [a bug that impact many quick action](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/29631).
This bug has been fixed. Looks like you just have to configure your editor:

> Add the following to an .editorconfig file at the root of your project:
> `dotnet_style_require_accessibility_modifiers = omit_if_default:suggestion`

See the options for `dotnet_style_require_accessibility_modifiers` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0040).

Comment: yes. also since the template says public for default it is obvious that it is the wrong one. but thanks anyway for trying to help. I added an image to show what iam trying to do.

Comment: @codymanix Mayby if it's roslynator (I don't use that tool), take a look here https://github.com/JosefPihrt/Roslynator/blob/master/docs/HowToConfigureRefactorings.md

Comment: it seems the only options that can be configured in roslynator are disabling analyzers/refactorings

Comment: @codymanix, I have edited my response with new information.

Comment: does not help either.